# mpi (message passing model)in c printf error

Tags: c, mpi

I am new to MPI. I am not figure out how to reslove it. In c printf shows the output but in mpi the printf function shows error...

**Code:**

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    // Get the number of processes
    int P;  //total number of processes 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &P);
    
    // Get the rank of the process
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME]; //256
 
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name);

    
    printf("\nHello world from process:%d out of %d, mapped on processor:%s\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: compile with `-Wall`, and fix the warnings related to `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing the argument in  ***MPI_Get_processor_name*** function

**replace** your function call with this line and initialise the length var (int)

```
 int name_len; //12 characters
 MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
```